# GLIBC_2.28 not found error when running lantern

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

When I run lantern on Ubuntu 18.04, nothing happens.

In terminal:

```
$ lantern 

Running installation script...

/usr/lib/lantern/lantern-binary: OK

/home/igwt/.lantern/bin/lantern: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /home/igwt/.lantern/bin/lantern)
```

Comment: Looks like something happened: You received an error message telling you what the problem is. However, your next problem is that glibc 2.28 is not in Ubuntu. Ubuntu 18.04 = glibc 2.27. Ubuntu 20.04 = glibc 2.31. Go back to Lantern and tell them that their installer is out of date.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is a headache. I live in China so this is crucial to me. I have no idea why the lantern developers do not keep things static with respect to the Ubuntu versions (I use Ubuntu 14.04 and also 18.04), regardless of the updates. It is so frustrating and inconvenient.

Latest lantern asks (mid 2020) for this damn libc.so.6 library version 2.28, which is found on Ubuntu above 19... WHY??? so ridiculous.

My healthiest solution has been to install older versions of lantern, the versions of the beginning of year 2020, or the version of mid year 2019.

If someone is in trouble I could send one of these by ftp or something.

Comment: I don't think installing older version works. Lantern would just download its own "*up-to-date*" version and install over `~/.lantern` ...The problem stems from the fact that they increased their ubuntu version in their build dockerfile from 18.04 to 20.10. https://github.com/xiaoqingfengATGH/lantern/commit/f1c95f86f0b043de9240e10efafbcc3f56983813#diff-dd2c0eb6ea5cfc6c4bd4eac30934e2d5746747af48fef6da689e85b752f39557